# SessionManagementFilter thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, spring-session

I'm facing some problems with concurrent session management, in particular when multiple concurrent requests are performed. Using this configuration:

```
 http
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
        .maximumSessions(1)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
```

a given user can create only one session at a time. It works, but when I try to login multiple times with many threads, the checks performed by `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` are bypassed. Looking at the implementation it seems that this class is not designed with thread-safety in mind:

```
    final List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(
            authentication.getPrincipal(), false);

    int sessionCount = sessions.size();
    int allowedSessions = getMaximumSessionsForThisUser(authentication);

    if (sessionCount < allowedSessions) {
        // They haven't got too many login sessions running at present
        return;
    }

    if (allowedSessions == -1) {
        // We permit unlimited logins
        return;
    }
```

Using an aspect to wrap the session authentication strategy inside a synchronized block fixes the problem, but I wonder if there is a better approach (or some configuration I've missed).

I've created a Spring Boot sample application reproducing the bug, hosted in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/daniloarcidiacono/sscce-spring-session-thread-safety). The main class is `PeakTest` along with `force-sync` property (please note that due to the non-deterministic nature of the test, results change between runs).

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you reported it to Spring Security?

Comment: Yes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5775

Comment: Thanks! I'm facing the same issue